# RDFS: How to subclass a FOAF class

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, rdfs, foaf

Is it possible to subclass a class found in FOAF (http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/)?
I tried something like the code below, but I am not sure if it is the proper way to do it or not.

```xml
<rdfs:Class rdf:ID="user"> 
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/#Agent" />
    <rdfs:comment> 
        The class of users, subclass of foaf:Agent.
    </rdfs:comment>  
</rdfs:Class>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your snippet, although not a complete RDF document, is the right way to make  `yourdoc#user` a subclass of `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/#Agent`.  However, that latter class is not the FOAF Agent class.  The FOAF Agent class is identified by the URI `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Agent` (with no `#`).  It might be useful to have a look at the actual [FOAF ontology](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/index.rdf), because you can see how it defines subclasses of Agent.  For instance, it declared foaf:Organization with

```xml
<rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Organization" rdfs:label="Organization" rdfs:comment="An organization." vs:term_status="stable">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Agent"/>
  <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"/>
  <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person"/>
  <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Document"/>
</rdfs:Class>
```

If you're writing this by hand, it's much easier to work in the Turtle or N3 serialization, where that would be:

```
foaf:Organization  a      rdfs:Class , owl:Class ;
        rdfs:comment      "An organization." ;
        rdfs:isDefinedBy  foaf: ;
        rdfs:label        "Organization" ;
        rdfs:subClassOf   foaf:Agent ;
        owl:disjointWith  foaf:Person , foaf:Document ;
        vs:term_status    "stable" .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Follow-up question: within the subclass of Agent (the User class described in the question), should I point to a property of Agent as `foaf:name` or `mydomain:name` ?

Comment: 1) a followup question should probably be posted as a new question, not as a comment on (an answer to) an existing one.  2) I'm not clear what you're asking.  You don't "point to a property", you use a property.  If an instance of User has a foaf:name, then you describe its name using foaf:name.